using jenkins crumb with rest api error 403
hello i need help with post req in Jenkins
i am using Jenkins 2.414.2
and i am trying to write a node.js script that create a new file and edit promotion
i am using axios so get the crumbs on jenkins/crumbIssuer/api/json
i am getting the crumb like i should
but when i am trying to pass them in the headers
(Jenkins-crumb:XXXX)
i am getting the error 403 for no valid crumb and i am also using api token and using auth in the headers
i looked on line and couldn't file solution for long time
i will be happy if someone can help me
thank!
i tryed to use crumb and apitoken

If you are using token authentication you don't need to provide a crumb. So the whole jenkins/crumbIssuer/api/json call can be dropped.
